# Transparent Circle inside a White Rectangle

Tags: image, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, shapes, snagit

I'm working on a report project and would like to avoid making a separate image for each indicator color.  Ideally, I like to put a transparent circle in a white rectangle.  I have Snag-It available and general Windows tools.

My plan is to put the Image in a table cell and change the color of the circle by dynamically assigning the background color of the cell.  I think it would be much easier to embed this one image, rather than creating a bunch of different colored circles that all have to be embedded.

Any suggestions on how I can do this in Snag-It or Paint, or any tools that are free for commercial use that you can recommended for this?

Comment: *"table cell"*? Are you talking about Excel? What's an *"indicator color"*? Is there a list of them? Your question context is hard to understand.

Comment: Reporting Services table.  Indicator color would be something like green is good, red is bad, etc.

Comment: SSRS 2012 has a built-in circular  indicator that can be embedded in a cell and is conditionally colored green/yellow/red based on an expression.  Is there some limitation of this you are trying to get around?  Your last comment suggests this is what you are looking for...

Comment: I need more than just 3 colors, such as blue & black.  In addition, I need to overlay text with conditional coloring inside the circle.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good workaround to get an indicator with whatever color you want.

Paint.net is a free image editor that you could create this in. Start with a white square. Use the Ellipse Select tool to select a circle in the middle. Press the Delete key to make it transparent. Save it as a .PNG file and embed it in the report.

Comment: I will give this a try.

Comment: @WesH did you get a chance to try this out? If it worked, please mark this as answered.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work as I needed it to.  I don't recall why.  Sorry, its been a while.